# method returning average of double array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Im new with programming and have been trying to solve this problem for a while, been looking at similar questions but im not understanding whats wrong with my code.

So the assignment is to write a method that takes an array that has three doubles in it. Then return the average of the three doubles. Then write a main that should call and then type the method.

Thanks!

Main

```
public class Tenta131031upg1main {
public static void main (String[]args){

    double []arr ={3.15, 4.41, 7.64};

    Tenta131031upg1.genomsnitt(double arr[]);

    System.out.println(Tenta131031upg1.genomsnitt(arr));

}

}
```

Class

```
public class Tenta131031upg1 {

static int i =0;
static double sammanlagd=0;
static double genomsnitt=0;

public static double genomsnitt(double[]arr){

    while(i<arr[].length()){                         
        sammanlagd = sammanlagd + arr[i];
        i++;
    }
    genomsnitt = sammanlagd/arr[].length();
    return genomsnitt;

}
}
```

PS. they are two different classes with 1 main and 1 class they are not in the same file!

The error:
Syntax error on token "double", new expected
    Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer
    arr cannot be resolved to a type

at Tenta131031upg1main.main(Tenta131031upg1main.java:7)

Comment: Well, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: `arr[].length()` is a syntax error, and not the only one. This code must be full of red markings from your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the two lines in the first file like this:

```
double[] arr ={3.15, 4.41, 7.64};

Tenta131031upg1.genomsnitt(arr);
```

You were creating a new, empty array in the second line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Main**

```
public class Tenta131031upg1main {
  public static void main (String[]args){

    double[] arr ={3.15, 4.41, 7.64};
    System.out.println(Tenta131031upg1.genomsnitt(arr));

  }
}
```

**Class**

```
public class Tenta131031upg1 {

static int i =0;
static double sammanlagd=0;
static double genomsnitt=0;

  public static double genomsnitt(double[] arr){

    while(i<arr.length){                         
        sammanlagd = sammanlagd + arr[i];
        i++;
    }
    genomsnitt = sammanlagd/arr.length;
    return genomsnitt;

  }
}
```

Changes are:

- change in method call
- arr.length instead of arr[].length()

Comment: Please remember that when you answer a Stack Overflow question, you are teaching somebody something about programming.  You should have `sammanlagd` as a local variable, not a field, in case the `genomsnitt` method gets called twice.  It's also very bad practice for a class to have a method and a field with the exact same name.

Comment: Agreed. Will keep in mind for the future sir! Abstained from making too many changes, as I assumed there might be some reason why the OP did not have the variable as local.